# ansible installation fails on control node, but not fails on local host itself?

Tags: ansible, centos7, yum

Description: Ansible yum module doesn't install through control host, but local yum install works perfectly? What could cause such issue? I appreciate any response. Thank you guys. I worked on this 8 hours, I have researched various of things, and tried very different approaches. No success. 
Node: Centos7 (newly installed), Control-Node: Ubuntu-LTS18.

Command:

```
 ansible ansitest2 -i ../inv -b -m yum -a "name=epel-release state=present"
```

it can be any package though.

This fails, however at the bottom I can see that it found the package and tried to install it. ([image: image attached here])

If I go to host itself and try to install it, it is successful. :

```
yum install epel-release -y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost 2 days on this, finally found answer, /etc/resolve.conf file needed to  be updated with option rotate timeout:1, 
So, if you have such issue, it is mainly about resolve.conf
man resolve.conf will give very good description.